# Making a property change when an animation ends?

Tags: game-engine, properties

I've been trying to make a blender game in first person, so i want to change the property "step" to one after a camera animation plays, then back to 0 after the second animation plays. So I was wondering if any of you could help me?

---

if you need more detail look down here:
(camera is turned at 90 degrees positive local x)

---

The first animation has the camera swings in the negative local y axis and turns back to 0 degrees.

---

the next animation swings in the positive local y axis and back to 0 degrees

---

Property "step" type Integer

Answer (score 1):

## Actuator sensor

The actuator sensor can tell you when an actuator deactivates. In your case it can listen to your action actuator.

*Remarks:*

- Ensure to evaluate the sensor status after the observed actuator gets activated. Otherwise you might trigger the next operation before the action actuator even started to play something.

## Frame property

The action actuator allows you to setup a property to receive the currently played action frame. With a property sensor you can sense over that property to act according to the current frame.

*Remarks:*

- To measure the end of an animation, you need to setup the end frame twice (at the action sensor and at the action actuator)
- Frames are no integer. Any equal checks will fail. You need to perform range checks.

## Frame counter / Time measurement

Establish a setup that constantly increases a property by one. This enables you to trigger actuators after certain frames.

*Remarks:*

- There is no direct relationship between counted frames and animation
- You need to be sure that the counted frame number matches what you are measuring (the duration of the animation).